# Why does John Travolta play a woman?

Tags: casting, hairspray

In the 2007 film Hairspray the character Edna Turnblad is played by John Travolta.  She's also played by a man in at least one stage production I know of.

Why? I know of the tradition in panto for women to play men and vice versa but why was the decision made here?

Comment: Right away I'd just say for a more comical or entertaining aspect, yet am looking forward to an actual answer. But wait, it actually seems to go back to the [2002 musical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairspray_%28musical%29) and the [1988 movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairspray_%281988_film%29) (starring [*Divine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_%28actor%29)) it was based on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**John Waters**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000691/), who wrote and directed the [original film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095270/) had this to say: 
(from the article [***Waters recalls men who played Edna***](http://variety.com/2007/legit/news/waters-recalls-men-who-played-edna-1117969969/))

> In the beginning, [*Divine*](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001145/) played the role of *Edna Turnblad*. And the first day on the set of “Hairspray,” I didn’t recognize him. I thought it was another neighborhood woman watching the shoot. We were filming in East Baltimore, and all the housewives were talking to him.
>
> Divine looked normal, not weird. It was a moment of truth. It was so anti-the-Divine-character that we started with. Divine said, *“Nobody can call me a drag queen, because what drag queen would allow themselves to look like this?”*
>
> **If there’s a template, that’s it for everybody who has played the role of Edna.** And they’ve all taken that to heart. **Edna Turnblad isn’t a drag-queen part.**
>
> **It has become a tradition for men to play her**, as with *Peter Pan*, where it is always [played by a woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan_%28play%29#Adaptations). **Why, I don’t know. It gives it an edge. It’s all about outsiders.**
>
> Divine played Edna realistically. The movie I made was actually realistic.

---

[**Neil Meron**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0581117/), who produced the [2007 film version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0427327/) (with John Travolta in the role) [said](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2007-07-19/news/0707190288_1_gay-issues-edna-turnblad-hairspray):

> **We hired an actor to play the role of Edna, not an actor to be a man wearing a dress** and a fat suit.
>
> John Waters never conceived of the role as a drag role. I mean, it happened to be that Divine was a drag queen, but **it's not a drag-queen role. The only tradition is that a man play the role of Edna.**